# How to specify an empty alias in Wix WebVirtualDir

Tags: wix, wix3.6

I am fairly new to the WiX world, so please bear over with me if the following question seems trivial.

I have a problem getting my WebVirtualDir alias to be empty. I.e. I would like to allow the user to specify the virtual directory, and if he does not then the web application is installed in the DefaultWebSite.

I have made a project that does everything correctly except that the user must clear the Virtual Directory when doing the installation in order to install in the DefaultWebSite. So what remains for me to do is the make the "default" virtual directory appear as empty.

My WiX fragment looks like this:

```
<Fragment>
<DirectoryRef Id="WEBINSTALLFOLDER" />

<ComponentGroup Id="IIS.Setup">
  <Component 
      Id="$(var.WebSiteName)" 
      KeyPath="yes" 
      Guid="$(var.WebsiteCode)" 
      Directory="WEBINSTALLFOLDER">
    <iis:WebSite 
        Id="WEBSITE_NAME" 
        Description="[WEBSITE_NAME]" 
        Directory="WEBINSTALLFOLDER" 
        ConfigureIfExists="no" 
        AutoStart="yes" 
        StartOnInstall="yes">
      <iis:WebAddress Id="AllUnassigned" IP="*" Port="80"/>
    </iis:WebSite>

    <iis:WebAppPool 
        Id="AppPool" 
        Name="[APP_POOL_NAME]" 
        ManagedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" 
        IdleTimeout="0" 
        RecycleMinutes="0"                
        ManagedPipelineMode="$(var.IIS_ManagedPipelineMode)" />

    <iis:WebVirtualDir 
        Id="vDir" 
        Alias="[WEB_APP_NAME]" 
        Directory="WEBINSTALLFOLDER" 
        WebSite="WEBSITE_NAME">
      <iis:WebApplication 
          Id="$(var.WebApplicationName)" 
          Name="$(var.WebSiteName)"
          WebAppPool="AppPool" />
    </iis:WebVirtualDir>
  </Component>
</ComponentGroup>

<Feature Id="IISSetup">
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="IIS.Setup" />
</Feature>
```

The I have tried multiple ways to do this, including:

- Removing the alias attribute from the WebVirtualDir : I know this was a nogo since alias is a required attribute
- Plainly setting the alias="" : Also a no-go but at least I get the error at compile time
- Setting up [WEB_APP_NAME] to be empty : but again I get a compile time error that the particular value may not be empty.

So what should I do to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the virtual directory to point at the root of the web site, set the `Alias` attribute to `'/'`.

Comment: That does not seem to be working. When trying to run the installer I get a permission denied on network location "/" (roughly translated from my local language).